# Error: Django-Social-Auth LinkedIn Client Error

Tags: django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth

After authentication I got this error message
HTTPError at /oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/

## 410 Client Error: Gone for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address,first-name,headline,id,industry,last-name)?format=json

#### Django settings conf

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'r_emailaddress', 
    'r_liteprofile'
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = [
    'email-address',
    'headline',
    'industry',]
```

======================================
Django package versions:

social-auth-app-django==3.1.0

social-auth-core==2.0.0

Django==2.1

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering in May of 2019, the PyPi version is still behind what is in master on Github and is using LinkedIn's deprecated `v1` API instead of the `v2`.

This worked for me:

`pip uninstall social-auth-core`

`pip install git+https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core`